# Comparing Time Strings in Swift

Tags: string, swift, parse-platform

In the app I am making when the view loads I want an object to be deleted in the background whenever the current time is greater than the given time.  Otherwise if the current time is less than the given time the object loads normally.  This is working fine for any time within the hour for example if the current time is 9:30 PM and the given time is 9:45 PM it works fine, but if the current time is 9:30 PM and the given time is 11:45 PM for some reason it doesn't know how to compare the hour so it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
 if timeString > End {
    self.SpotterMap.removeAnnotation(SpotAnnotation)

    let endTime = End

    let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "SpotInfo")
    query.whereKey("spotendtime", equalTo: endTime)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                object.deleteInBackground()


            }

        }
    })

    print ("spot removed")
}
```

Can anyone give a solution to my problem? 
Thanks

Comment: without knowing the values of the variables, it's hard to tell. I suggest you go through de app using some breakpoints and take a look at the variables

Comment: @Glenn I gave an example of the variables in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to work with times, you need to work with the `NSDate` type representation of your dates for the best accuracy, not a string one.
You will need to change your parse class `spotInfo` and add a column of type `date`, lets say you call it "realSpotEndTime".

To compare the times use `.compare` directly on the NSDates, if the dates return true when ordered ascending, it means that the first date comes before the second one. So your `if` statement would become;

(note: to get the **real** current time, you need to instantiate NSDate() right before comparison)

If this returns true and executes it means that the current time on the phone is less compared to the `End` time, remember, End needs to be in NSDate type as well, not string

```
let currentTime = NSDate()
//currentTime < End
if (currentTime.compare(End) == .OrderedAscending) {
  ...
  query.whereKey("realSpotEndTime", lessThanOrEqualTo: currentTime)
}
```

or, alternatively you could do check if the current time is past the end time by

```
//End < currentTime
if (End.compare(currentTime) == .OrderedAscending) {
// fix parse query here
}
```